# Suggestions to create a table or to design a stored procedure to remove while loops

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql, stored-procedures

The company I am currently working for, has a scenario for which we have to use while loops or cursors in SQL. Which has a huge performance impact in our case, hence, I want to optimize it.

The scenario is we have a table called `DocType`, think of it as a main table. A column in this table `Name` contains data like `PO_Invoice, NON-PO_Invoice, GRN`. Now, there are other tables, which are like `XXX_PO_Invoices, XXX-PO_Invoices, XXX_GRN`. So basically, there are queries running on the `DocType` table, which gets the name, then we have to add the `XXX` part to those names, and query in the tables `XXX_PO_Invoices, XXX-PO_Invoices, XXX_GRN`. The queries running on the `DocType` table, gives different results depending on the requirement so we can't hard code it.
To query into the `XXX` tables, we are using While loops. Is there a better way to achieve this? Like creating a new table? Or can there be something done in the queries itself.

Table definition for DocType -

```
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsAP] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ImportType] [int] NULL,
    [ImportTypeConfig] [int] NULL,
    [IndexingType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ExtractionType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OutgoingEmailAddress] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MonitorEmail] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [InputFolder] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ArchiveFolder] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [OutputFolder] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [StorageFolder] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ExportFolder] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [FTP_URL] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ExternalValidationEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ApprovalEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CodingEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ManualVerificationEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PostApprovalEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PostEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [InputFolder_Conversion] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [IsRealIndexExtraction] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [StoreSupplierTemplate] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AcceptHardCopy] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DestructionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [DisplayName] [nvarchar](550) NULL,
    [RenameFile] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDocumentRecord] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SendInvalidAttachmentNotification] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SendReassignNotification] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AddEmailMetadataToComment] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AddEmailAttachmentToDocument] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SendCodingNotification] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SendApprovalNotification] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [InputFolder_HTML_Conversion] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ManualSeperationEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [WizardStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDefaultLine] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsGRN] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsPO] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [POMatchingEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [RequestParkReason] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [RequestDeleteReason] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [RequestReverifyReason] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsManualMonitor] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ManualMonitorFolder] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [SplitFolder] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [BaseCurrency] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AutomaticCodingEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DisplayLineTotals] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [hasRelatedDocuments] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HardDeleteInMonths] [int] NULL,
    [CopyPOLinesInVerification] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsBudget] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HasBudget] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [POLineMatching] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsSupplierReconciliation] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SendDocumentRejectedNotification] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [GenerateOnTheFly] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LogoFile] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [RequestRecreateReason] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentTypeGroup] [int] NULL,
    [POOriginatorAccessEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DocumentType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [PostApprovalEnabled]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsRealIndexExtraction]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [StoreSupplierTemplate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AcceptHardCopy]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [RenameFile]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [CreateDocumentRecord]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [SendInvalidAttachmentNotification]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [SendReassignNotification]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AddEmailMetadataToComment]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AddEmailAttachmentToDocument]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [SendCodingNotification]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [SendApprovalNotification]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ManualSeperationEnabled]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((2)) FOR [WizardStatus]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CreateDefaultLine]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsGRN]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsPO]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [POMatchingEnabled]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RequestParkReason]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RequestDeleteReason]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RequestReverifyReason]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsManualMonitor]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AutomaticCodingEnabled]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DisplayLineTotals]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [hasRelatedDocuments]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CopyPOLinesInVerification]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsBudget]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [HasBudget]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [POLineMatching]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsSupplierReconciliation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SendDocumentRejectedNotification]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [GenerateOnTheFly]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RequestRecreateReason]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentType] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [POOriginatorAccessEnabled]
GO
```

Table definition for one of the XXX_table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Doc_IE10_POInvoices](
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdated] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [Supplier_Name] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Supplier_Code] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Invoice_Number] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Debit_Credit] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [PO_NUMBER] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Invoice_Date] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [Currency] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Net_Total] [DECIMAL](18, 4) NULL,
    [Tax_Total] [DECIMAL](18, 4) NULL,
    [Invoice_Total] [DECIMAL](18, 4) NULL,
    [Template_Type] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [SAP_Reference] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [SAP_PaymentDueDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [SAP_Status] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Description] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Company_Code] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Debit_Credit_Type] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [ParkReason] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [PaymentTermsDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [Invoice_Comment] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Original_PO_NUMBER] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Doc_IE10_POInvoices_636945689932953689] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The `XXX_` is actually just `'Doc_'`. My bad to make it more confusing. Below is one of the queries which uses loops.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllPONumberInInvoices_OLD] @invoice_table   NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
     BEGIN
         
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PONumbersInInvoices') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #PONumbersInInvoices;

        CREATE TABLE #PONumbersInInvoices
        (
            ID INT,
            PO_NUMBER NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Supplier_Name       NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Supplier_Code       NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Net_Total           decimal(18,4),
            Tax_Total           decimal(18,4)
        )

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MultiPONumbersInInvoices') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #MultiPONumbersInInvoices;

        CREATE TABLE #MultiPONumbersInInvoices
        (
            ID INT,
            PO_NUMBER NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Supplier_Name       NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Supplier_Code       NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Net_Total           decimal(18,4),
            Tax_Total           decimal(18,4)
        )

        DECLARE @QueryToBeExecuted NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @QueryToBeExecuted = '
            INSERT INTO #PONumbersInInvoices
            SELECT  [Id],[PO_NUMBER],[Supplier_Name], [Supplier_Code], [Net_Total], [Tax_Total]
            FROM ' + @invoice_table + '
            WHERE [PO_NUMBER] NOT LIKE ''%,%'' AND IsActive = 1'

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @QueryToBeExecuted
            
        SET @QueryToBeExecuted = '
            INSERT INTO #MultiPONumbersInInvoices
            SELECT  [Id],[PO_NUMBER], [Supplier_Name], [Supplier_Code], [Net_Total], [Tax_Total]
            FROM ' + @invoice_table + '
            WHERE [PO_NUMBER] LIKE ''%,%'' AND IsActive = 1'

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @QueryToBeExecuted

        DECLARE @MultiPOIndex INT= 0;
        DECLARE @MultiPOCount INT;

        SELECT @MultiPOCount = Count(*) FROM #MultiPONumbersInInvoices;

        WHILE(@MultiPOIndex < @MultiPOCount)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @InvoiceId Int;
            DECLARE @PONumber NVARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @Supplier_Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @Supplier_Code NVARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @Net_Total decimal(18,4)
            DECLARE @Tax_Total decimal(18,4)

            SELECT TOP(1) @InvoiceId = Id, @PONumber = PO_NUMBER, @Supplier_Name = Supplier_Name, @Supplier_Code = Supplier_Code, @Net_Total = Net_Total, @Tax_Total = Tax_Total FROM #MultiPONumbersInInvoices
    
            INSERT INTO #PONumbersInInvoices
            SELECT @InvoiceId AS Id, [Value] AS PO_NUMBER, @Supplier_Name AS Supplier_Name, @Supplier_Code AS Supplier_Code, @Net_Total AS Net_Total, @Tax_Total AS Tax_Total
            FROM dbo.Split(@PONumber,',')

            DELETE FROM #MultiPONumbersInInvoices
            WHERE Id = @InvoiceId;

            SET @MultiPOIndex += 1;
        END


        SELECT * FROM #PONumbersInInvoices

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PONumbersInInvoices') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #PONumbersInInvoices;
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MultiPONumbersInInvoices') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #MultiPONumbersInInvoices;
     END;
```

The @invoice_table is then fed by another procedure which does the below

```
SELECT Id,
                'Doc_'+Name AS TableName
         INTO ##DocumentTypes_with_POMatchingEnabled
         FROM DocType
         WHERE(POMatchingEnabled = 1)
              AND IsActive = 1 and IsAP=1;

WHILE(@Index < @DocumentTypes_with_POMatchingEnabledCount)
             BEGIN
         
                 DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(150), @PoTable NVARCHAR(MAX), @GrnTable NVARCHAR(MAX), @PO_NUMBER NVARCHAR(MAX);
                 DECLARE @DocumentTypeId INT, @DocumentRecordId INT, @DocumentTypePoId INT, @DocumentTypeGrnId INT, @DocumentId INT;
                 SELECT TOP (1) @TableName = TableName,
                                @DocumentTypeId = Id
                 FROM ##DocumentTypes_with_POMatchingEnabled;

                 -- GET PO NUMBERS IN INVOICES
                 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PONumbersInInvoicesTemp') IS NOT NULL
                     DROP TABLE #PONumbersInInvoicesTemp;
                 CREATE TABLE #PONumbersInInvoicesTemp
                 (ID            INT,
                  PO_NUMBER     NVARCHAR(MAX),
                  Supplier_Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
                  Supplier_Code NVARCHAR(MAX),
                  Net_Total     DECIMAL(18, 4),
                  Tax_Total     DECIMAL(18, 4)
                 );
                 INSERT INTO #PONumbersInInvoicesTemp
                 EXEC GetAllPONumberInInvoices
                      @invoice_table = @TableName;

                 -- GET DOCUMENT TYPE ID OF PO 
                 SELECT @DocumentTypePoId = dt.Id,
                        @PoTable = 'Doc_'+dt.Name
                 FROM DocumentTypeAssociation dta
                      INNER JOIN DocumentType dt ON dt.Id = dta.DocumentTypeId2
                 WHERE DocumentTypeId1 = @DocumentTypeId
                       AND dt.IsPO = 1;

                 -- GET DOCUMENT TYPE ID OF GRN
                 SELECT @DocumentTypeGrnId = dt.Id,
                        @GrnTable = 'Doc_'+dt.Name
                 FROM DocumentTypeAssociation dta
                      INNER JOIN DocumentType dt ON dt.Id = dta.DocumentTypeId2
                 WHERE DocumentTypeId1 = @DocumentTypeId
                       AND dt.IsGRN = 1;
                 DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
             
                 SELECT @SqlStatement = ('
            INSERT INTO ##InvoicesWithPoAndWithoutGrnReportResults 
            SELECT docPO.Id AS DocumentId, 
            docInvoice.PO_NUMBER AS PO_NUMBER, 
            '''+@TableName+''' AS INVOICE_TABLE, 
            '''+@PoTable+''' AS PO_TABLE, 
            '''+@GrnTable+''' AS GRN_TABLE, 
            docInvoice.Supplier_Name, 
            docInvoice.Supplier_Code,
            CASE
                    WHEN docPO.Originator LIKE ''%_@__%.__%'' 
                    THEN docPO.Originator 
                    WHEN '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @userMappingTableId)+' > 0 
                    THEN ( SELECT TOP 1 [Value] 
                        FROM LookupDataCustom 
                        WHERE DocumentTypeId = '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @DocumentTypeId)+' 
                            AND IsActive = 1 
                            AND LookupDataTableId = '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @userMappingTableId)+' 
                            AND [Value] LIKE ''%_@__%.__%'' 
                            AND [Name] = docPO.Originator) 
                    ELSE '''' END AS Originator,
            case when DocumentRecord.Status =5
            then
            '''+@loginUrl+'Document/Verify/''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DocumentRecord.Id) else
            '''+@loginUrl+'Document/View/''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DocumentRecord.Id)
            end,
            docInvoice.Net_Total, 
            docInvoice.Tax_Total
            FROM #PONumbersInInvoicesTemp docInvoice 
            inner join DocumentRecord on DocumentRecord.DocId=docInvoice.Id and DocumentRecord.DocumentTypeId='+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @DocumentTypeId)+'
            INNER JOIN '+@PoTable+' docPO ON docPO.PO_NUMBER = docInvoice.PO_NUMBER and docPO.Supplier_Code = docInvoice.Supplier_Code and docPO.IsActive = 1
            LEFT JOIN '+@GrnTable+' docGRN ON docGRN.PO_NUMBER = docInvoice.PO_NUMBER and docGRN.Supplier_Code = docInvoice.Supplier_Code and docGRN.IsActive = 1
            WHERE  docGRN.Id IS NULL
            and DocumentRecord.Status in (5,24,28)      
            ' + @grnNotificationDelay + '
            Order by docPO.Originator,docInvoice.Supplier_Name;
            ');
                 EXEC sp_executesql
                      @SqlStatement;
                 DELETE FROM ##DocumentTypes_with_POMatchingEnabled
                 WHERE Id = @DocumentTypeId;
                 SELECT @Index = (@Index + 1);
             END;
```

Didn't share the entire query because it might be more confusing.

Comment: I think you've described what you are doing, not why you are doing it.  Hard to provide a satisfactory answer just staring at code.

Comment: You could get rid of those `WHILE` loops and do everything in one go. For example you could do `CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(@PONumber,',') WHERE [PO_NUMBER] LIKE ''%,%''` and avoid the whole MultiPO loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide an example of the queries you're currently using, and your table definitions, in your post. As it stands now, your question isn't very clear, especially on *how loops are even relevant here*.

That being said, with the current information you provided, it sounds like you guys could possibly benefit from [dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-sql-in-sql-server/) by leveraging the system stored procedure [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Using dynamic SQL, you can build a SQL string of the queries you want to run off the table names stored in your `DocType` table. Then you can execute it with `sp_executesql`.

You can also use the system view [`sys.tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as a way to get a list of the actual table names for your "XXX" prefixed tables. Technically you could do a wildcard join between it and your `DocType` table to help build the dynamic SQL, like so:

```
SELECT T.[name]
FROM sys.tables AS T
INNER JOIN DocType AS D
    ON T.[name] LIKE '%' + D.[Name]
```

This is assuming when you say "XXX", you're using that as a placeholder in your question, but in reality it's a different set of values. But if you mean they do specifically all start with three X's, then you don't even need the aforementioned query. Rather you can just prepend the "XXX" yourself when selecting from your `DocType` table like so:

```
SELECT 'XXX_' + [Name]
FROM DocType
```

If it's true you have both names prefixed with an underscore and others with a dash, you can do a combination of both aforementioned queries to ensure you only select valid table names, using a `UNION ALL`, like so:

```
SELECT 'XXX_' + D.[Name]
FROM DocType AS D
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T
    ON 'XXX_' + D.[Name] = T.[name]

UNION ALL

SELECT 'XXX-' + D.[Name]
FROM DocType AS D
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T
    ON 'XXX-' + D.[Name] = T.[name]
```

If you update your post as I initially mentioned, we can probably provide you more specific advice.

Comment: I have updated my question with the information you asked for. We can use the UNION ALL thing, but in our case we number of records we get from the DocType  table is different for different clients. So, we want something more generic.

Comment: I don't understand this point: "*...number of records we get from the DocType table is different for different clients. So, we want something more generic*", could you please elaborate?

Comment: So the thing is, we have multiple clients and each client have their own database. The tables are same in all the databases but the data is different( for obvious reasons). So  if a query returns 10 rows from DocType table from DB1, it might return 5 rows from DocType table from DB2, again because they are different clients with different data. Hence, we want to something generic which can be applied to all the DBs and also is scalable. I hope its more clear now. Let me know if its not, I will try again.

Comment: @JR92 I understand what you're saying now, thanks. It doesn't matter each client database will return different number of records, the `UNION ALL` query will still work in each of them fine. I have to read through your updates more closely to try to understand your main goals though, as there's a lot of code. Maybe you can add to your post what the purpose / goals of the code is?

Comment: The goal of the query/queries is to first filter out data from the DocType table using some conditions on the columns -> Get the 'Name' and add 'Doc_' to the names -> The 'Doc_Tables' are related to each other by PO_Number and Supplier_Code columns -> So we have to join them and use the conditioning filters to get the final result. So basically, our main results come from the Doc_Tables but we have to do all Joins and filters with DocType table because all the other tables in the DBs are related to DocType table.